# Why does closure matters?

Tags: closures

What is advantage of closure vs class, and why closure has advantages? Class has data and behavior/methods that operates upon these data. If anyone can answer me this question? I am coming from OOP background, and I don't see that paradigm "code as data" so clear. Is it composition in functional languages that matters?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The main advantage is that it enables you to create private scope and avoid affecting code outside of the closure by introducing global variables etc.
It's a very common pattern to use in JavaScript.

Comment: Class has private scope too

Comment: Yes it does, but not all languages have classes.

Comment: Let's say C#. Why does it matter in language like C#?

Comment: It serves the same purpose, but it's probably less important in c# since it offers granular scope limitations as part of the language. My primary usage of it is in JavaScript.

Comment: I am familiar with module pattern and can see it in JS, but not so clear in C# or Java. Pass function as variable, but I can pass class that has function too, so where is closure advantage?

Answer (score 0):

You can put variables in a class (in many languages, anyway) but then the functions on that class share the exact same set of variables. You could also create an object to hold the variables and define the function on the object, but then the primary "thing" of interest is the object, whereas you might not care about the variables (except when you first initialize them), only the function.

Let's say you want to create functions at runtime that do basically the same thing but with different variables (e.g., each function spits out the next value of a collection that's given to it when the function is defined). You can't do it with class variables and a class function (method) because the class variables are shared (i.e., you have only one function and it works on a single collection at a time).

You could create an object that holds the initial value (i.e., the collection) and define a function on the object that references those values. If what you really want is a *function*, though, then this object might seem unnatural: after all, you're carrying around an object to hold your collection, a pointed to the next element to emit, and the function to emit it, whereas you just want a function.

A closure is a natural way of creating such a function. When you create the closure, it gets a private set of variables that retain their value between function calls, but these variables (the referencing environment) are hidden. If you tried to implement the same thing with an object, you'd be dealing with the object first and your function second, even though the "thing" of interest to you is the function (and once you're initialized those variables, you don't care about them).

---

Here's a use case: callbacks.

Suppose you want to use the same callback function in many places and at many times, but you want it to be called not just with the event object but also some data to specify when you set it up. For example, suppose your function is called `myFunc(event)` and when it's called, you want it to log a string that you pass, so you really want to define it as `myFunc(event, string_to_be_logged)`, like this:

```
function myFunc(event, string_to_be_logged) {
  ...do stuff...
  log(string_to_be_logged);
}
```

The framework that invokes the callback expects a function and nothing else and invokes it with just the event object. If you only do this once or twice, you might define two versions of your callback:

```
function myFuncABC(event) {
  ...do stuff...
  log("ABC");
}

doSomethingAsyc(&myFuncABC);   // pass the pointer to the callback function

function myFuncDEF(event) {
  ...do stuff...
  log("DEF");
}

doSomethingAsyc(&myFuncDEF);
```

but you can see the problem with this!

Instead, we can create the callback function dynamically, as a closure:

```
function createCallback(str) {
  var myFunc = function(event) {
                 ...do stuff... 
                 log(str);
               }
  return myFunc;
}
```

Tthe function we're generating is a closure because it retains its referencing environment: the `str` variable. Every callback function we generate this way gets its own private copy of `str`.

Now, we can do the following:

```
var mf1 = createCallback("ABC");
doSomethingAsyc(myFunc);    // pass the variable containing the callback function
var mf2 = createCallback("DEF");
doSomethingAsync(mf1);
```

and the first callback will log "ABC" while the second one logs "DEF".

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to answer Mark Westling, but I don't see anything that you said that I can't do with classes.

Comment: Is it maybe easier way to do composability, to pipe line of functions based on some underlaying library that allows that, so closure will keep result of previous operations and feed next one in pipe with that result?

Comment: There's also nothing I said that can't be done in assembly language :-)  It's actually more about readability that funcationality. Let's say I want a function that emits an element of a list every time I call it. I could create an object that encapsulates the list and the pointer, call that object X, and then use X.next_value(). Or, I could create a closure called next_x() and use it instead. You make a good point about composing functions and I see that as an advantage of using closures too (though I don't think I've ever done that).

Comment: Can I say that for example LINQ pipes operators like: 
string[] names = { "Tom", "Dick", "Harry", "Mary", "Jay" };
Enumerable<string> query = names .Where (n => n.Contains ("a")) .OrderBy (n => n.Length) .Select (n => n.ToUpper());
So in this case Select makes closure over OrderBy(operations and data) that again makes closure over Where(operations and data)  that again makes closure over names(only data in this case).

Comment: Mark Westling, your thoughts are interesting, but I believe functions and closures are about functionality not readability :)

Comment: Just added an example that I hope helps!

Comment: Mark Westling: your example is same as creating two instances/object of same class with different private variables that you provide via constructors. These objects operates on these data with methods define within.